# Why i'm getting the same echo in preventing double submitting?

Tags: php, forms, cookies

Hello i have my form and i want to implement this method for preventing double submitting on forms or going back 
The simple  code:

```
 <?php
            // start session
            session_start();

            // create unique token
            $form_token = uniqid();

            // commit token to session
            $_SESSION['user_token'] = $form_token;
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Prevent multiple POSTs </title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form action="submit.php" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="bar" />    
        <input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="<?php echo  $_SESSION['user_token'];  ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And here the submit.php code:

```
       <?php 
        session_start();
    //We check if the token of the page and session match!
    if($_POST['user_token'] == $_SESSION['user_token']) {
        $message = 'Your download is <a href="foobar.xls"> Here </a> ';
    } else {
        $message = 'Your request has expired, please go back and resubmit!';
    }

    echo "We say: " . $message;


// invalidate the token so it expires on view, important!
unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
?>
```

I uploaded this script to my server but whenever i click the submit button i get the same answer the `We say: Your download is Here` echo , why this i checked if my cookies are created and yes they exists as they should ,

i want that users that have submitted the form once , to cant do that another time until a refresh or setting a maximum time that these cookies can exists and than delete them so that the user after for eg 10 min can submit another form if he want so

Any help will greatly be welcomed. Thanks in advance. Updatet

Comment: If the token in the session and the token in the form are the same, how are they supposed to work? You need to generate 2 tokens, one in the form and another one associated but hidden from the client.

Answer (score 2):

```
session_start();
```

Add this in the begining of second script which recive your data from form.
More detailes [in manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php).

But the only way to recieve msg 'Your request has expired' you need to keep recieved data in some form on server (file or data base) I suppose.

Comment: Fine yet i'm getting the "We say: Your download is Here" message but if i go back and click submit again it's bringing me again to that message ? instead of  "our request has expired, please go back and resubmit!" thanks between

Comment: @NewLogo that message will always be the same because you are setting it in the page and then putting the value in the hidden field. So every time that you submit the form, `$_POST['user_token']` and `$_SESSION['user_token']` will have the same value. It would be a different message if you reload the page, because then `$_POST['user_token']` should have the old value and `$_SESSION['user_token']` will be unset

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro i reload the page but again the same ?

Comment: Alvaro Montoro - you are right, after refresh value will be different, but the result of the script will be still the same, because this updated value will be sent throw post and throw session.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was a bit puzzled by that

Comment: @DaneSoul How can i archive that can you please explain me or  just write me the code based on my example i'm searching for this for like a week and if we could make it work it would be awesome , thanks